# Minimum time to start the race

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

There are N bikers present in a city (shaped as a grid) having M bikes. All the bikers want to participate in the competition, but only K bikers can be accommodated in the race.

In order to minimize the time to start the race, bikers move for getting the bikes spread in the city in such a way that first K bikes are acquired in the minimum time.

Every biker moves with a unit speed and one bike can be acquired by only one biker. A biker can proceed in any direction. Distance between bike and bikers is euclidean distance.

**What would be the square of required time to start the race as soon as possible.?**

EXAMPLE : Let say we have N=3 that means 3 bikers  and let say M=3 meaning 3 bikes are their and suppose K=2 means we need only 2 bikers for race

Coordinates of bikers are : (0,1),(0,2),(0,3)

Coordinates of bikes are : (100,1),(200,2),(300,3)

**Then here answer will be 400** as there’s need for two bikers for the race. The first biker (0,1) will be able to reach the first bike (100,1) in 100 time units. The second biker (0,2) will be able to reach the second bike (200,2) in 200 time units. This is the most optimal solution and will take 200 time units. So output will be 200^2 = 40000.

Help to solve this problem?

Constraints are : N,M <= 250

Comment: Are there any particular requirements, or are you looking for a brute-force solution? Regardless of that, which approaches have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write down the M*N edges between bikes and bikers. Start throwing them away one by one, longest to shortest, and when the last edge that connects a particular bike (or biker) is thrown away, eliminate that bike (or biker) too. Stop when you cannot pair K bikes to K bikers any more. (This can be tested by e.g. running the [Hopcroft–Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) at each step).

The last edge thrown away (its length squared) is your answer.

Comment: What you mean by throwing an edge?Could you please provide some pseudocode or so for your algorithm?

Comment: Moreover how are you ensuring that one bike is acquired by only one biker ?

Comment: By throwing away X I mean the following: at step N you have a set `S` that contains `X`, an step N+1 you replace it with a set `S'=S\\{X}`. I think you should try to come up with an implementation yourself.

Comment: What about complexity of your algorithm?Though i didnt get it completely..:(

Comment: The second question might be a problem, let me think about it a bit.

Comment: Yes there's indeed a problem, I have edited the answer to include a more complex (correct this time, I hope) stopping criterion.

Comment: I think its too inefficient as hopcraft run in O(n^2.5) and checking it each time will lead to approx O(n^4) algorithm for this question

Comment: You can speed up Hopcroft-Carp by (1) stopping at match cardinality K and (2) using use results from a previous run. Indeed if a step broke the matching by throwing away an edge that participates in the matching, you only need to find one augmenting path to restore cardinality K.

Comment: @user3343643 However, the pointer to matchings in general should be helpful here: It seems like you want to compute some form of a (weighted) matching http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm#Weighted_matching , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs With some additional constraints (e.g. not all nodes have to be in the matching). An (optimal) solution for that might not be trivial

Comment: @n.m I think their can be easier and efficient solution for this problem.Perhaps Dynamic Programming may help?

Comment: @n.m Whats your second optimisation .I didnt get that.Please explain